# CountDownLatch not freeing thread

Tags: java, android, concurrency, kotlin

I have a method, which loading image from Firebase Storage. It's called in background thread, and I need to block it, until image is loaded (to avoid callback hell). Here is the code (in Kotlin)

```
override fun fromNet(): Bitmap? {
    Log.wtf(TAG, "$name loading from firebase")
    var result: Bitmap? = null
    val lock = CountDownLatch(1)
    try {
        FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(FIRE_STORAGE).child(ctx.getKGL().famkey)
            .child(name).getBytes(524288L)
            .addOnFailureListener {
                Log.wtf(TAG, "$name load failure")
                lock.countDown()
            }
            .addOnSuccessListener { bytes ->
                Log.wtf(TAG, "$name loaded")
                val b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.size).scale(ctx.dip(64))
                result = b
                lock.countDown()
                ctx.saveToCache(name, b)
            }
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                Log.wtf(TAG, "on complete")
                lock.countDown()
            }
    } catch (ignored: NullPointerException) { lock.countDown() }
    lock.await()
    return result
}
```

But thread stays blocked forever

Logcat:

```
A/MemberPhoto: xvd6z67gZfMCLG4c9mkGXKe9ML53 load failure
A/MemberPhoto: on complete
```

UPD: May the cause be, that Firebase code is Java, and my code is in Kotlin?

Comment: Well, `lock.await()` will never unblock at least if `NullPointerException` is thrown in the `try` block before `lock.countDown()` is called. Isn't it the case?

Comment: @hotkey I thought, if exception is thrown - await() won't be called. But let me check

Comment: My bad, I didn't spot the `return null` in the `catch` block. Sorry.

Comment: I replaced `return null` with `lock.countdown` - still an issue

Comment: do you see the log messages in your log, indicating that the listeners have been called? if so which message do you get?

Comment: you should modify your code to call `lock.countDown()` in a `finally` block, indeed here if `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.size).scale(ctx.dip(64))` fails, `lock.countDown()` is never called

Comment: @NicolasFilotto if he calls `lock.countDown()` in the finally block then it will never wait. the finally is on his main thread that is supposed to wait.

Comment: @DimaRostopira can you show the logged messages as requested, they are evidence.

Comment: @JaysonMinard I believe that you missunderstand my proposal, what I propose is to put code of listeners in try/finally blocks and call lock.countDown() in the finally blocks to ensure that it will be called whatever happens

Comment: @NicolasFilotto I see messages in logcat, and can catch this lines with debugger. All three listeners are called, onComplete always, onFailure and onSuccess depends on result. Also I put `lock.countDown()` in catch block, updated code

Comment: @NicolasFilotto ah, makes sense if the failures are within the callbacks.  Good plan.

Comment: @DimaRostopira the last proposal of Nicolas was to make sure within each callback you have a `try...finally { lock.countDown() }` so that any errors during the callback don't prevent the countDown call (which would cause this to lockup).  it is likely your only hole in the code if something like `decodeByteArray` fails with exception.

Comment: @JaysonMinard then there will be no wait, firebase spawns new thread and finally will be called before file loaded. But I will try surround `decode...` with try catch, but this doesn't makes sense, since onCompleted called always

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to be sure that `lock.await()` won't make your current thread wait forever, you need to ensure that `lock.countDown()` is called whatever happens so here you should surround with a `try/finally` block the code of your listeners in order to call `lock.countDown()` within a `finally` block.

Indeed otherwise with your current code if for example `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.size).scale(ctx.dip(64))` fails, `lock.countDown()` will never be called which will make the thread calling `lock.await()` wait forever.

*For example in case of a success the code of your listener should rather be:*

```
.addOnSuccessListener { bytes ->
    try {
        Log.wtf(TAG, "$name loaded")
        val b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.size).scale(ctx.dip(64))
        result = b
    } finally {
        lock.countDown()
    }        
    ctx.saveToCache(name, b)
}
```